# Fine-uploader : validate and submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I have a form and Fine-uploader trigger.

This is my html code :

```
<div id="fine-uploader-trigger"></div>
<form action="new.php" name="user_video" method="post" id="qq-form">
    <input type="text" name="mytext">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

This is my javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            autoUpload: false,
            chunking: {
                enabled: true,
                concurrent: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                success: {
                    endpoint: "/libs/fine-uploader/endpoint.php?done"
                }
            },
            debug: true,
            element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-trigger'),
            request: {
                endpoint: "/libs/fine-uploader/endpoint.php"
            },
            resume: {
                enabled: true   
            },
            retry: {
                enableAuto: true,
                showButton: true
            },
            template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
        });

        qq(document.getElementById("trigger-upload")).attach("click", function() {
            manualUploader.uploadStoredFiles();
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on "Submit", my file is uploaded but my form is not submited : I can't save with my PHP Script (new.php).

I tried this but this is same :

```
callbacks: {
    onAllComplete: function(succeeded, failed) {
        $('#qq-form').submit();
    },
},
```

Can you help me ? Thanks :)